# Count unique no. of records from a column with where condition in different column in mysql

Tags: mysql

My MySQL table is

[image]

I want to count different leave types from `leaveType` column, where team is `HR`.

My current code is:

```
SELECT COUNT(leaveType = 'Priviledge') as Priviledge, 
    COUNT(leaveType = 'Causal') as Causal 
FROM emp_leave_tracker WHERE team='HR' GROUP BY leaveType;
```

Comment: What you want to do is a pivoting of a count+group of leaveType. You can find useful answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns

Comment: and what's your problem .. you have error  ?? wrong result  .. update your questioon add  a proper data sample  .. and the expected  result

Comment: Why not a simple select leaveType, count(*) from emp_leave_tracker WHERE team='HR' GROUP BY leaveType;

Comment: Is 'privileDge' even a word?

Comment: @Strawberry sorry. Its privilege. typing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(`leaveType` = 'Priviledge',1,0)) as `Priviledge`,
    SUM(IF(`leaveType` = 'Causal',1,0)) as `Causal`
FROM emp_leave_tracker 
WHERE team='HR';
```

The IF statement inside the sum returns a 1 when the leave type matches it's value, and 0 if not. The SUM function then adds up all the ones.

Comment: @AlokRoutray In MySQL, you can leave out the IF(,1,0). And to accord with your dataset, you would also omit the 'd' ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry.